# How to use Nightwatch.js to load other js framework?

Tags: javascript, extjs, nightwatch.js

I need to develop automated tests for an application created in `extJS` and I was planning to use **Nightwatch.js** to create tests.

It is possible to load the `extJS` framework through **Nightwatch.js** to be possible use the functions of extJS (search functions of elements)? Because each time the page is loaded, the IDs from the elements can change.